# SSRS - Show a rectangle based on selected parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a quick question?

I have a report that contains a "TicketNo" parameter. This is a dropdown list and contains 2 types of values (example below)

'82736 - Change Request'
'78382 - Report Request'

How can I make a rectangle visible depending on which type of ticket was created? (Report request or change request)

So if a change request was selected, the rectangle showing change data would appear, and vice versa?

Appreciate any help as always!

Comment: a conditional expression changing background colour may help, see http://it.peikkoluola.net/2013/09/25/create-conditional-formatting-in-report-builder/

Comment: Looked at this but not sure it's what I am after?

Comment: What is the rectangle used for? Should it contain any data? Should is be displayed in the report area?

Comment: The rectangle will contain data based on what parameter was selected

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rectangle object type in the Report Item Toolbox.

There you can set the border Style property to Solid an then add an Expression to its BorderColor property.

Write the expression as a conditional statement, setting it to Black or white depending on your condition, using an IIF statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the visibility property of the rectangle

- Goto Rectangle Properties
- Select visibility
- Choose 'Show or hide based on an expression'
- Input expression '=Parameters!TicketNo.Value=82736' assuming ticketNo is integer

Rectangle will be hidden if the condition is true.

Comment: Hi, how would I get this to work dynamically though? For example, the available tickets will change day on day.. so one day it might be 82736 another day it might be 27362? Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi, You can get the current value from a DataSet SQL query. The report contents are static until reloaded, but when the report is (re)loaded, it will be refreshed.

Comment: You need to determine how the report knows what type of ticket it is and build your expression from there. For example, if the parameter label or value has the words "Change Request" in it then the visibility expression would be something like `=Parameters!TicketNo.Value.ToString().Contains ("Change Request")` Change .Value to .Label if the description rather than the value contains these words.